# Counting time to open .pptx file in python

Tags: python

I want to count time needed to open .pptx file, not until it closed, but until it opened completely.

I use `os.system(''.join(["loimpress ",filename]))` to open .pptx file

If i use following code

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
os.system(''.join(["loimpress ",filename]))
tdelta = datetime.datetime.now() - d1
print(tdelta.total_seconds())
```

Time counted if i've close it.

Comment: We can understand your question. But can you also explain why do you think your implementation is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that, on UNIX-like systems like OSX or Linux, depending on the program you are launching, this program is "blocking" the main program. The operation `os.system(whatever)` terminates, when the program launched terminates. I don't know the mechanics on Windows systems, they are probably the same.

You might want to look at the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess). Then, look for some kind of output, that Libreoffice prints to the command line once loading a file has finished. The subprocess module makes it possible to look for that output.

Many programs tend not to output anything or, even branch into background, so look at Libreoffice's debug and verbosity command line options. Good luck!